# Converting Multiple Images to PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, file, pdf, stream, itext

I am trying to convert a series of images taken from `OpenFileDialog()` to one PDF using `iTextSharp` in `C#`. Here is what I'm running. When I select files I get the error: `"System.NotSupportedException: 'Stream does not support reading.'"`

on the line :

```
var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
```

I am wondering what this error means, or what I could fix to resolve the issue. Thanks.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog { Multiselect = true, Filter = "Image files | * .jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;" };

    // Open file button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Run code only if a file is selected
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            using (var stream = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                foreach (String file in ofd.SafeFileNames)
                {
                    using (var imageStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
                        doc.Open();
                        var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
                        doc.Add(image);
                        doc.Close();
                    }


                }
            }


        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the main code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add also main method - The entry point

Comment: Just a guess here, but could it be because of `var imageStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create` which would be overwriting the image files? I think it should be FileMode.Open

Comment: @Prany I have added the main code.

Comment: @Hack I have added the new line to reflect that. Now I am getting an error about 'cannot access a closed file'.

Comment: @John, instead of opening and closing `doc` within the foreach loop, I'd suggest opening the document, adding all the images, then closing it. The cause of that error is from calling `doc.Close()` which closes `stream` to test.pdf.

Comment: @John - not sure if that's correct. I have used your code with no changes and have put the image files inside bin/debug folder and it works without any error.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below, I've moved the opening and closing of `doc` outside of the foreach loop. Calling `doc.Close()` closes the parent file stream, so it's important to only call doc.Close() once all the images have been added.

```
using (var stream = File.Create("test.pdf"))
using (var doc = new Document())
using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream))
{
    doc.Open();

    foreach (var file in ofd.SafeFileNames)
    {
        using (var imageStream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            var image = Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
            doc.Add(image);
        }
    }

    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am getting "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'" when using this code when it runs and loops through the first time.

Comment: @John, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I upvoted because this certainly fixes one problem. As for the "index was outside the bounds of the array" error: if this code was used literally, then this error is probably caused by a specific image. We'd need the specific image in order to reproduce the problem. Note that some image problems were fixed over the years. You are still using iTextSharp (which no longer exists); today, we talk about iText for .NET. You're using iText version 5 or earlier; today we're at version 7. Maybe the problem you report was fixed a long time ago.